# How to monitor SqlClient SqlException events?

Tags: c#, sqlexception, sqlclient

Visual Studio 2019 .NET Core C# Windows Forms development.

`SqlDependency.Start` is causing a `SqlException`. But it happens after `.Start` completes with return code `True`. So catch does not catch it. Happens periodically. Can see it in VS Output:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.SqlClient.dll

Checking SSMS log file:

> Service Broker needs to access the master key in the DB. Error 32.

But I see this once. Whereas VS Output shows `SqlException` in groups of 5 separated by tens of seconds.

In general how can one setup a way to monitor all `SqlException` that happen outside of a response to a call. Say a time out exception perhaps not that I know if it happens.

In particular suggestions for resolving this are appreciated. I tried setting TRUSTWORTHY to YES but it did not help.

Not sure if `SqlException` and the log message are related.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That an exception is thrown is not necessarily an issue. It's quite normal for exceptions to be thrown. The VS debugger will show you every exception that is thrown but the vast majority of those are being thrown, caught and dealt with in system code and are most likely of no concern to you.

That said, you can configure VS to break whenever a particular type of exception is thrown, rather than the default of when it goes uncaught. While debugging, open the *Exception Settings* window, find the exception of interest and check the corresponding box to break whenever that exception gets thrown. It seems that you want the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` under the *Common Language Runtime Exceptions* node.